# How to declare `#include` for a header file to avoid `error lnk2005`

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

I created a new WIN32 C++ project. I didn't touch any of the code in the main file yet, and started to write my code in a different file `objectsFW.cpp` the definitions for the file are located in the file `objectsFW.h`.

`objFW.h` looks like:

```
#pragma once

double g;

typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
}Vector;

typedef struct {
    //...
}BoundingBox;

typedef struct {
    //...
}Ball;

Vector operator + (Vector a, Vector b) {
    //...
}

Vector operator - (Vector a, Vector b) {
    //...
}
```

There are some more operators defined, and the declarations of the functions.
I included the header file in the source file (`objectsFW.cpp`), and also, added it to the `Resources.h` file, so that my code will be useable in the main program.

I get linker errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: "struct Vector __cdecl operator*(struct Vector,double)" (??D@YA?AUVector@@U0@N@Z) already defined in ObjectsFW.obj   C:\testC\ObjectsCollision\ObjectsCollision\ObjectsCollision.obj ObjectsCollision
...
Error   4   error LNK2005: "struct Vector __cdecl operator+(struct Vector,struct Vector)" (??H@YA?AUVector@@U0@0@Z) already defined in ObjectsFW.obj    C:\testC\ObjectsCollision\ObjectsCollision\ObjectsCollision.obj ObjectsCollision
```

and so on.

I know that this happens because the `#include "objectFW.h"` line appears two times (once in each .cpp file). The question is what is the right way to declare the header file to avoid linker errors?

---

### UPDATE:

After turning the operator functions to `inline` most of the errors fixed, there is still a program with the line:

```
double g;
```

the error is:

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: "double g" (?g@@3NA) already defined in ObjectsCollision.obj C:\testC\ObjectsCollision\ObjectsCollision\ObjectsFW.obj    ObjectsCollision
```

(working on Visual Studio 2012)

Comment: Declare the operators `inline`.

Comment: ^ Either declare them `inline` or implement them in a `.cpp` file.

Comment: In C++, you don't need the `typedef struct {} my_struct` idiom.  You can use the shorter syntax: `struct my_struct {};`  Are you programming in C or C++?  This is one place where the languages differ.

Comment: Also, don't place global variables in header files.  Place the variable in a source file and place the "extern" declaration in the header file.  Also, do your best to eliminate global variables; they cause many problems, especially in multi-threading environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in your header:

```
extern double g;
```

And in a .cpp:

```
double g;
```

That way every file that includes the header will know that there is a variable g, but it will only be declared at one place.

Answer (score 4):

About global variables:
1. Refrain from using them.  Think *encapsulation* and *data hiding*.
2. If you must use them, define the global in 1 source file and place the "extern" in a header file.

Example:
*header_file.hpp:*

```
  extern unsigned int deadly_global;
```

*source_file.cpp:*

```
  unsigned int deadly_global;
```

### Better method for hiding global variables

A better method for controlling (hiding) global variables is to place all the code that uses the variable in the same source file and declare the variable as `static`:

```
  static unsigned int variable_shared_by_many_functions = 0;
  void f1(void)
  {
    variable_shared_by_many_functions = 42U;
  }

  void f2(void)
  {
    std::cout << "Value of shared variable: "
              << variable_shared_by_many_functions
              << "\n";
  }
```

### Controlling Global Variables Using Getters and Setters

If you must share the variable among functions in more than one source file, a safer technique is to declare the variable as static in one source file and declare functions (interfaces) to access it.

```
  static int dangerous_variable = 0;

  int accessor(void)
  {
     // Return a copy of the varible.
     return dangerous_variable;
  }

  void setter(int new_value)
  {
    if ((new_value / 5) != 1)
    {
       dangerous_variable = new_value;
    }
  }
```

This technique allows you to place filters or other controls on setting the variable.